# Accessing the values of variables that are within an object property's string value? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, object, amazon-s3

When using AWS S3 headObject function I receive a Javascript object that has a property named Restore that is either set like this:

```
{
     Restore: "ongoing-request=\"false\", expiry-date=\"Sun, 13 Aug 2017 00:00:00 GMT\""
}
```

Or like this:

```
{
    Restore: "ongoing-request=\"true\""
}
```

I would like to access and work with the values inside the Restore property's string value i.e. the ongoing-request variable and the expiry-date variable but the problem is they are within the string. How can I best parse Restore property's String value so that I can get the values of ongoing-request and expiry-date and set them to Javascript variables so that I can do things like:

```
if(ongoingRequest === "true") {
    console.log("Bla bla bla");
}
```

Or:

```
let date = new Date(expiryDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the values using regular expressions and [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). Here is an example:

```js
const exampleOne = "ongoing-request=\"false\", expiry-date=\"Sun, 13 Aug 2017 00:00:00 GMT\"";
const exampleTwo = "ongoing-request=\"true\"";

console.log(parseRestore(exampleOne), parseRestore(exampleTwo));

function parseRestore(str) {
  const ongoing = str.match(/ongoing-request=\"(true|false)\"/);
  const expiry = str.match(/expiry-date=\"(.+?)\"/);
  return {
    'ongoing-request': ongoing[1] === "true", 
    'expiry-date': (expiry || [])[1]
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is more general than the approach from Andre Nuechter. I parse the string for all properties not only for ongoing-request and expiry-date.

First I replace the inner double-quote-marks with single-quote-marks because they are easier to handle. Than I split globally the string with string.match in an array of strings from the properties with their values. I accept there at the end of each string an optional comma with space ", " which is needed for seperation of the entries.

Now I add to an result-object all properties. For this I search for a string (the prpertie-name) at beginning followed by equal-sign and in quote-marks another string
(the property-value). At the end their is excepted an optional comma with space. From the string-match result i can get the name and value of the property, so I can add it to the result.

```js
function parseRestore(test) {
  test =  test.Restore.replace(/\"/gi,"\'");
  
  let entries = test.match(/[^=]+=\'[^\']+\'(, )?/g);
  let result = {};

  for (let i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    let entrySplit = entries[i].match(/^(.+)=\'(.+)\'(, )?$/);
  
    result[entrySplit[1]] = entrySplit[2];
  }
  
  return result;
}

let test_1 = {
     Restore: "ongoing-request=\"false\", expiry-date=\"Sun, 13 Aug 2017 00:00:00 GMT\""
};
let test_2 = {
    Restore: "ongoing-request=\"true\""
}

console.log( parseRestore( test_1 ) );
console.log( parseRestore( test_2 ) );
```